# Need help for this JS code:Show more results

Tags: javascript, string, math, innerhtml, operation

I hope you'll help me because I can't find a good solution for this problem:

```
calculate: function() {
        var distanza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('persentage').value);
        var secondi = parseFloat(document.getElementById('coin').value);
        var minuti = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor').value);
        var result = document.getElementById('result');

        result.innerHTML = (((coin*(60))+ valor)/(persentage/100)).toFixed(2);

    }
```

No problem, it works.
But if I try to add another `innerHTML` for showing another operation result, it doesn't work.

```
calculate: function() {
    var distanza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('persentage').value);
    var secondi = parseFloat(document.getElementById('coin').value);
    var minuti = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor').value);
    var result = document.getElementById('result');

    result.innerHTML = (((coin*(60))+ valor)/(persentage/100)).toFixed(2);

} calculate: function() {
    var distanza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('persentage').value);
    var secondi = parseFloat(document.getElementById('coin').value);
    var minuti = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor').value);
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var result = document.getElementById('result1');

    result.innerHTML = (((coin*(30))+ valor)/(persentage/100)).toFixed(2);

    result.innerHTML = (((coin*(30))+ valor)/(persentage/50)).toFixed(2);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is the solution:
you must create different function name for any result and don't create make multiple strings name "result", "result1" etc. he creates an error in the program and won't work.
Thanks to @tymeJV

ah sry, I have another question:
how could I add an instance if else 
for example: if result<80 print the result else x=(result - 60) and print "10+x"

Comment: Change the variable name: `var result1 = document.getElementById('result1');` and then `result1.innerHTML = (((coin*(30))+ valor)/(persentage/50)).toFixed(2);`

Comment: You also have 2 `calculate` functions - name them differently.

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks you, it works